# UIButton and UISlider in tap conflict

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a strange problem. The designers provided me with a design (no change possible) that puts a button quite near a slider. 
For the sake of explanation, let's talk about left side.
The button only registers the tap from approx. two thirds of its width from the left. If I tap further to the right, the tap is registered in the slider.`
Even if I change the Z order of those controls in IB, it still happens.

Why and what would be the solution to make the whole area of the button register the tap for itself?

Answer (score 0):

You should respect the Apple HCI guidelines, they are there for a reason. Have a word with the designers ;-j

Comment: Did'n I say in my post it's impossible?

Comment: @EarlGrey, yes you did, and my answer was admittedly polemical, but this is something I feel strongly about. Is there no way you can feed back to the designers in an informed manner as to why their design makes no sense from a UI point of view? If _you_ disagree with my sentiment, perhaps you could post an image of the design in your question. But the way you have described it, this is an issue which, if solved technically, would created a bad experience for the user.

Comment: Actually, I agree with the design, its kind of an edge case, but a valid one. Unfortunately i cant post it, it contains proprietary UI.
The problem is cased by a somewhat sloppy Apple UISlider implementation imho.

Comment: Two suggestions spring to mind (not fully thought through) - subclass UISlider and intercept the gestures - and/or a bit of hit testing..?

Comment: strange that the z order isn't being respect when the hit test is happening. My half thought out answer would be to override some UIControl methods, add breakpoints in them, and figure out whats going on.